# concat overlapping data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm working on merging 2 data frames together that are all structured in the same fashion:

df1:

```
DATE   TANK#1 TANK#2 TANK#3 TANK#4 ... TANK#100
9/22   10     30     22     13         62
10/19  5      29     17     13         51
```

df2:

```
DATE   TANK#3 TANK#4 TANK#5 TANK#6 ... TANK#120
11/17  10     30     22     13         62
11/29  5      29     17     13         51
```

df1 has the date range 9/22/16 - 10/19/16

df2 has the date range 10/24/17 - 05/28/17

I would like to concat these DataFrames together so all of the dates are in one DataFrame. However, the column headers/tanks are not all the same for each data frame. It is mostly overlap, but some tanks exist in one and not in the other.

I tried

```
result = df1.append(df2)
```

But receive the error: `Plan shapes are not aligned`

What is the best way to merge data shaped like this?

Comment: As you've shown it, when I run `df1.append(df2)` I do not get an error.  It's on you to provide sufficient information to reproduce the problem.  Its what we refer to as [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Set 'DATE' as index and combine df1 and df2 using combine_first.

```
df1.set_index('DATE').combine_first(df2.set_index('DATE')).reset_index()
```